# How do two PCs communicate on an isolated LAN disconnected form the internet? Do they have IP adresses?

Tags: ip, ip-address, lan

I am given to understand that in order to send data using the TCP/IP protocol suite you need two IP addresses (sender and receiver). My question is, how does communication happen on an isolated LAN. Say I have two PCs connected with an ethernet cable (There is no DHCP sever and IP addresses weren't set manually), do they choose random IP addresses (to please the TCP/IP suite), or do they send IP packets with emtpy TO and FROM fields? or something else?

Comment: Do you mean peer to peer?

Comment: They get IPs.  Windows will auto-assign in the 169.254.0.0/16 range.  This [question on SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/238625/why-is-windows-default-ip-address-169-xx-xx-xx) has more details.  Suggest that this belong on SU rather than SO.

Comment: Thanks! and thanks for the redirection, im just a regular noob here so.. :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use IP, you must have an IP address.  Most devices will auto-assign themselves an address in the 169.254.0.0/16 block if a DHCP server is unavailable.

You should also note though that there are many other protocols available, such as IPX/SPX, but most of them are not used these days.